# flask run does not run after setting environment variables - Flask not found

Tags: python, windows, flask

In one sentence: **"My Flask app does not launch after setting shell variable `FLASK_DEBUG=1` while in Windows 10 but works in Linux"**

I'm following Corey Schafer's Flask tutorial on YouTube, running Windows 10 Pro 1903 and using PowerShell as my terminal. I've got my venv set up with the basics (using Python 3.7.3):

```
pip list

Package Version 
------------ ------- 
Click 7.0 
Flask 1.1.1 
itsdangerous 1.1.0 
Jinja2 2.10.1 
MarkupSafe 1.1.1 
pip 19.2.2 
setuptools 41.2.0 
Werkzeug 0.15.5 
wheel 0.33.6
```

I then set `$env:FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py`

All is well when running the app using `flask run` but after setting:

```
$env:FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

And running `flask run` again, I get the following error:

> c:...\flask_blog\venv\scripts\python.exe: No module named C:...\flask_blog\venv\Scripts\flask

Has anyone experienced this before? I can confirm that I installed Flask while in my virtual environment using pip install flask.

It gets more interesting -- when I attempt the same on my Ubuntu 19.04 machine (I repeated the tutorial steps separately on both machines) everything works without an issue. The virtual environment on both machines is created using `virtualenv venv` and from there I immediately run `pip install flask`.

I could just proceed with the tutorial on my Linux machine but I need this to work in Windows 10.

Comment: How are you invoking the flask command?

Comment: Directly from the terminal `flask run`